# Firing a function ONCE in a animation loop Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function sayHello () {
  consile.log('hello')
}

animate () {
 sayHello();
 Window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

Is there a way to make this sayHello function fire only once? Perhaps using async await? Or maybe some completely other way I'm ignorant to. I'd love to learn!

Naive solution:

What I've been doing is making some kind of global flag variable.

```
let saidHello = false;

animate () {
if(saidHello === false) {
 sayHello();
 saidHello = true;
}
 
 Window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

This works but seems messy and is hard to follow at times. Perhaps there is a best practice for firing a function ONCE in an animation loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a helper `once` to wrap your `sayHello`. The higher-order function takes a function as an argument and return a new function that will run only once

```js
const once = fn => {
  let called = false, result;
  return (...args) => called ? result : (called = true, result = fn(...args));
};

const sayHello = once(() => {
  console.log('hello');
});

function animate() {
  sayHello();
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

Version with `if` instead of the ternary operator `?`:

```
function once(fn) {
  let called = false, result;
  return (...args) => {
    if (!called) {
      result = fn(...args)
      called = true
    }
    return result
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. You mind dumbing it down a bit? The new age syntax is tripping me up a bit.

Comment: I added also a "traditional" version.

Answer (score 2):

What if you just called it before starting the animation???

```js
function sayHello() {
  console.log('hello')
}

function animate () {
 window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

sayHello();
animate();
```

Comment: Or use a generator.

Answer (score 1):

Just define some boolean to detect if the function has been executed or not with `isFired` variable like this:

```js
let isFired = false;
function sayHello () {
  if(isFired) return;
  isFired = true;
  
  console.log('hello')
}

function animate () {
 sayHello();
 window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```